# Create a timestamp virtual column from a text column

Tags: mysql, timestamp, virtual

I need to add a virtual column in a MySQL table that stores a timestamp value generated from another column (of the same table).

I can't convert my existing column to timestamp because it could break many other processes so, to query faster my database, I need a column with the same data but with proper format.

I tried to create a virtual column with the default value of

```
TIMESTAMP('field_date_text')
```

but the result is `NULL`. The `'field_date_text'` field has format `"d/m/Y H:i"`

What's the right syntax to add a virtual column as Timestamp from another field?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `TIMESTAMP()` or `UNIX_TIMESTAMP()` and/or `STR_TO_DATE()`:

```
TIMESTAMP(STR_TO_DATE(field_date_text, '%d/%m/%Y %h:%i'))
```

or

```
UNIX_TIMESTAMP(STR_TO_DATE(field_date_text, '%d/%m/%Y %h:%i'))
```

or just `STR_TO_DATE()`:

```
STR_TO_DATE(field_date_text, '%d/%m/%Y %h:%i')
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved using this function as virtual calculated value

```
TIMESTAMP(str_to_date('field_date_text','%d/%m/%Y %H:%i'));
```

Comment: Glad you have solved it @SmurfXXX ! Don't forget to accept forpas answer.